# No overload matches this call decrpyt string in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Hello everyone i have written the code for encrypting string, but now i want to decrypt them for the next process this is my code .

```
export const decrypt = (text: string) => {
  try {
    if (!ENCRYPTION_KEY) {
      throw new Error("encrypt_Key is not set");
    }
    const texts = text;
    let textParts = texts.split(":");
    let iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift(), "hex"); // this error here with no overload Overload 1 of 4, '(arrayBuffer: WithImplicitCoercion<ArrayBuffer
    let encryptedText = Buffer.from(textParts.join(":"), "hex");
    let decipher = createDecipheriv(
      "aes-256-cbc",
      Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY),
      iv
    );
    let decrypted = Buffer.concat([
      decipher.update(encryptedText),
      decipher.final(),
    ]);
    return decrypted.toString();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The call does not match any overload of `Buffer.from`. `Buffer.from` accepts `(string, encoding)` but your call is `(string|undefined, encoding)`.

Typescript, in this case, already helps you to check iv variable. And makes sure it is not undefined.

Some solutions to fix it

```
    let textParts = texts.split(":");

    // problem: typeof textParts.shift() = string | undefined
    let iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift(), "hex");

    // if you want to use default value
    iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift() || "your default value", "hex");

    // if you want to handle error, validate your value before put it in the call
    const strIV = textParts.shift()

    if(!strIV) {
        throw new Error("INVALID_FORMAT")
    }

    let iv = Buffer.from(strIV, "hex");
    
    // if you're 100% sure that it can not be undefined
    let iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift() as string, "hex"); // cast to string
    let iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift()!, "hex"); // non-null assertion
```

I think the second fits with your code as I see in the question.

Comment: thank you with your suggestions . I have done with this one  , but It's still show the error